# Undefined reference to Eclipse C++ with libraries MySQL Server and Connector C++

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse-cdt

As it is my first question on the forum, please be forgiving with style issues.

I've been looking for information to solve this but the problem hasn't reached a solution. I ask here in the hope someone will know. In need of implementing a MySQL database inside a C++ environment, I've [followed the steps in this video, about how to setup MySQL in such a way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNniOHn9Xe0&list=WL&index=127&t=668s&ab_channel=TenorGames). However, when trying to build the simple .cpp used there I've been unable to achieve in making it work. From what I have been reading, I can tell my errors are related to the linker, but I do not know how to correct them.

It may not be important, but note that I use Eclipse in contrast to the person of the video, that works with Visual Studio.

Error from console:

```
C:\Users\quimi\Desktop\eclipse\AskACountryC++\Debug/../MySqlTest.cpp:15: undefined reference to `mysql_init@4'
C:\Users\quimi\Desktop\eclipse\AskACountryC++\Debug/../MySqlTest.cpp:17: undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect@32'
C:\Users\quimi\Desktop\eclipse\AskACountryC++\Debug/../MySqlTest.cpp:24: undefined reference to `mysql_query@8'
C:\Users\quimi\Desktop\eclipse\AskACountryC++\Debug/../MySqlTest.cpp:27: undefined reference to `mysql_store_result@4'
C:\Users\quimi\Desktop\eclipse\AskACountryC++\Debug/../MySqlTest.cpp:28: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_row@4'
C:\Users\quimi\Desktop\eclipse\AskACountryC++\Debug/../MySqlTest.cpp:35: undefined reference to `mysql_error@4'
```

The project's Include paths in GCC C++ Compiler:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include"
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\include"
```

The Libraries in MinGW C++ Linker:

```
:libmysql.lib
:mysqlcppconn.lib
```

And the Library search path in MinGW C++ Linker:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib"
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\lib64\vs14"
```

Any idea about what can be happening and what could be a solution? Anything would be appreciated.

The `.cpp`:

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int qstate;

int main()
{
    MYSQL* conn;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    conn = mysql_init(0);

    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "password", "testdb", 3306, NULL, 0);

    if (conn) {
        puts("Successful connection to database!");

        string query = "SELECT * FROM test";
        const char* q = query.c_str();
        qstate = mysql_query(conn, q);
        if (!qstate)
        {
            res = mysql_store_result(conn);
            while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
            {
                printf("ID: %s, Name: %s, Value: %s\n", row[0], row[1], row[2]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Query failed: " << mysql_error(conn) << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        puts("Connection to database has failed!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you building in 32 bit, when your linked libraries are in 64 bit?

Comment: The libraries are in 64 bit. I'm building with "MinGW - Minimalist GNU" and Eclipse. I have read that the programs produced by MinGW are 32 bit. Could that be the cause of the trouble?

Comment: yes . that is your issue then. If you build in 32 bit , it will not link to 64 bit libraries. Either get your dependencies in 32 bit, or build your program in 64 bit.